# Find value of dictionary inside a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have some data like this:

```
{'cities': [{'abbrev': 'NY', 'name': 'New York'}, {'abbrev': 'BO', 'name': 'Boston'}]}
```

From my scarce knowledge of Python this looks like a dictionary within a dictionary.

But either way how can I use "NY" as a key to fetch the value "New York"?

Comment: Sorry, could you explain better what you want?

Comment: Would this be only abbreviation to name or would it also work the other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [**`next`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next) and filter the sub dictionaries based upon the `'abbrev'` key:

```
d = {'cities': [{'abbrev': 'NY', 'name': 'New York'},
                {'abbrev': 'BO', 'name': 'Boston'}]}

city_name = next(city['name'] for city in d['cities']
                 if city['abbrev'] == 'NY')

print city_name
```

Output:

```
New York
```

Comment: The other suggestions would maybe also work. But as I got this to work easily for my purpose I mark it as (an) Accepted reply. Thanks all who contributed.

Answer (score 3):

When you've got a dataset not adapted to your need, instead of using it "as-is", you can build another dictionary from that one, using a dictionary comprehension with key/values as values of your sub-dictionaries, using the fixed keys.

```
d = {'cities': [{'abbrev': 'NY', 'name': 'New York'}, {'abbrev': 'BO', 'name': 'Boston'}]}
newd = {sd["abbrev"]:sd["name"] for sd in d['cities']}
print(newd)
```

results in:

```
{'NY': 'New York', 'BO': 'Boston'}
```

and of course: `print(newd['NY'])` yields `New York`

Once the dictionary is built, you can reuse it as many times as you need with great lookup speed. Build other specialized dictionaries from the original dataset whenever needed.

Comment: That's clever and it can be reused for the other abbreviations as well! But given the "scarce knowledge" (stated in the question) you should probably include how to access `"New York"` in the final dictionary :)

Answer (score 3):

It's a dictionary with one key-value pair. The value is a list of dictionaries.

```
d = {'cities': [{'abbrev': 'NY', 'name': 'New York'}, {'abbrev': 'BO', 'name': 'Boston'}]}
```

To find the `name` for an abbreviation you should iterate over the dictionaries in the list and then compare the `abbrev`-value for a match:

```
for city in d['cities']:        # iterate over the inner list
    if city['abbrev'] == 'NY':  # check for a match
        print(city['name'])     # print the matching "name"
```

Instead of the `print` you can also save the dictionary containing the abbreviation, or return it.

Comment: great for order and pedagogy

Answer (score 0):

I think that I understand your problem.

`'NY'` is a value, not a key.

Maybe you need something like `{'cities':{'NY':'New York','BO':'Boston'}`, so you could type: `myvar['cities']['NY']` and it will return `'New York'`.

If you **have to** use `x = {'cities': [{'abbrev': 'NY', 'name': 'New York'}, {'abbrev': 'BO', 'name': 'Boston'}]}` you could create a function:

```
def search(abbrev):
    for cities in x['cities']:
        if cities['abbrev'] == abbrev:
            return cities['name']
```

Output:

```
>>> search('NY')
'New York'
>>> search('BO')
'Boston'
```

**PD:** I use python 3.6

Also with this code you could also find abbrev:

```
def search(s, abbrev):
    for cities in x['cities']:
        if cities['abbrev'] == abbrev: return cities['name'], cities['abbrev']
        if cities['name'] == abbrev: return cities['name'], cities['abbrev']
```